# jQuery + jEditable - Prevent Submit for Custom Input

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker, jeditable, onsubmit

I am using jEditable plugin with the datepicker but I need validation for the date before submit it to the database. So i edit the jEditable-datepicker.js to something like this:

```
submit: function (settings, original) {
    var form = this;
    var tid = $(original).attr('id');
    var input = $(original).find('input');
    var newDate = input.val();
    alert('id' + tid);
    alert('newdate' + newDate);
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '/Stock/CompareDate',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: tid, inputDate: newDate },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            if (result < 0) {
                alert("Expiry dare cannot be earlier than storage date");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                alert('else');
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
},

/* attach jquery.ui.datepicker to the input element */
plugin: function (settings, original) {
    var form = this,
      input = form.find("input");

    // Don't cancel inline editing onblur to allow clicking datepicker
    settings.onblur = 'nothing';

    datepicker = {
        dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy'
    };

    input.datepicker(datepicker);
}
```

I get the alert in the if statement, which means the validation method works, but the invalid value still get submitted to the database. I dont know why the return false dint stop the submit action.. I had tried to solve this problem for a long time, yet this is the time i get closest to the solution. I just dint know how can i stop submission in the if statement...

Do really need help here... Thanks....

(UPDATE: add in html)

My date field is in a table:

```
        <td id="sdat@(item.FoodID)" class="storagedatepicker">
              @String.Format("{0:ddd, d MMM yyyy}", item.StorageDate)
        </td>
        <td id="edat@(item.FoodID)" class="expirydatepicker">
              @String.Format("{0:ddd, d MMM yyyy}", item.ExpiryDate)
```

The call to jeditable is like this:

```
    $('.expirydatepicker').editable('@(Url.Action("Edit", "Stock"))',
    {
        type: 'datepicker',
        indicator: 'saving...',
        event: 'dblclick',
        tooltip: 'Double click to edit...',
        submit: '<img src="../../Content/Add_in_Images/ok.png" alt="ok"/>',
        cancel: '<img src="../../Content/Add_in_Images/cancel.png" alt="cancel"/>',
        style: 'inherit'

    });
```

Comment: Hi, i add in the html, both my date field is in a table

Comment: Still not clear to me where the submit function is being called

Comment: hi, the submit function should called from the script "submit" which i included in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it work by not trying to stop the submission, but replace the input value with the default value if the validation failed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but maybe still useful to others, just `return false;` from `onsubmit` parameter function to avoid its submission, for example:

```
$('.editable').editable('/someurl', {

    ... // all your jeditable settings

    onsubmit: function (settings, original) {

        if (<conditions to not submit>)
            return false;

    }
});
```